# How to pass a Salesforce html formula URL prefilled into a FormAssembly field into a HTML image or hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, html, salesforce

I have a Salesforce formula field that yields the following url formula: https://microcollege.tfaforms.net/4852324?CommUserID=0056g000005mRFD&ConID=0036g00000kuRzo&SchoolID=&email=test@test.com&name=Test

FormAssembly Prefill connector pulls the URL into a FormAssembly form and I'm assigning it as a Javascript variable named "ApplicationURL". I'd like to pass ApplicationURL into an HTML href button with a static image.

HTML:

```
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="application_URL"><img style="max-width: 
100%;height: 60px;" alt="Apply" src="//microcollege.tfaforms.net/forms/get_image/1/pTC9C8qKq4Rt5niNfwTToFP09IsMdkqPUXjsqcGcX0gNWrB2tpq3uh0wlBdk5jbd-ApplyButtonwithdocument.png">
</a>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var application_URL = ApplicationURL; 
</script>
```

Somehow the HTML is yielding the URL of the current page, rather than the one that I want to be the page that it dynamically links to using the Salesforce formula URL.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. First you want to make sure you are getting the right value from your prefill connector. If you just put the value into a field and display it, do you get the value you expect? After that's working, try a simple JavaScript alert to see if your variable is set right.  Once that's all working a JS based approach like the answer from @bleau should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id="button">
  <img style="max-width: 100%; height: 60px;" alt="Apply" src="//microcollege.tfaforms.net/forms/get_image/1/pTC9C8qKq4Rt5niNfwTToFP09IsMdkqPUXjsqcGcX0gNWrB2tpq3uh0wlBdk5jbd-ApplyButtonwithdocument.png">
</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  const a = document.getElementById('button').href = ApplicationURL
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Bleau. I tried inserting your JS into the FormAssembly JS editor for the page and updating the HTML to reflect your code suggestion. The HTML wasn't functional as with your code. I tried amending to <a href id="button">, which FormAssembly turned into <a href="" id="button">. Regardless, this yielded the current page's URL, not the URL that I needed from the application_URL variable. Any additional thoughts?

Comment: I am not familiar with FormAssembly but if it works like normal html and javscript the updated solution should work. In your example you are passing a string to href and not your variable. If you cant hardcode the link (href="https://microcollege...") then you need to use javascript to get the element and then assign an href attribute with your the url as its value.

Comment: Your code worked. I just needed to change the way that I was attempting to pass the variable in. Thanks for your help!